# Which API should I use to detect when the user is walking in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-api

I am trying to figure out which google API can be used in order to detect whether the user is walking or just standing. Is there any API that requires only sensor values and not GPS?

Comment: Its already answered, you can check here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993993/how-to-detect-walking-with-android-accelerometer>

Comment: What I am asking is completely different. I asked if there is any API, not an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [step counter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) if available and [fused location](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) otherwise.

Step counter is lightest to use and consume less battery in comparison to fused location.

Even more, step counter allows indoor discovering.

Fused location might be not enough inside buildings and you'd probably have to use another solution like [beacons](https://developers.google.com/beacons/). It gets more complicated here.

Comment: Fused location is accurate when GPS is on, right?

Comment: @TinaLooke as the name suggests fused location uses both GPS and Wifi. It can be used without GPS enabled but for best results it's better to turn it on.

Comment: The problem is that it makes it impossible to be accurate when indoors

Comment: @TInaLooke you can go ahead and use beacons https://developers.google.com/beacons/ when you're indoor. Step counter seems to be most relevant solution anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use `FusedLocationProviderApi` in Android to get location of device and then fetch `speed` on the `Location` object.

If the speed is greater than 0, then you can say user is moving. The speed is in meter/second.

Refer Android Documentation to understand code : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi