# Detect if phone is moving up or down using accelerometer and count changes

Tags: android

I would like to detect using accelerometer if phone is moving up or down and how many times direction was changed.

I am using this code:

```
lastY = 0;
lastYChange = 0;
initialized = false;

...

if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

...

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float y = event.values[1];

        if (!initialized) {
            lastY = y;
            initialized = true;
        }
        else {
            float yChange = lastY - y;
            float deltaY = Math.abs(yChange);

            if (deltaY < 2) {
                deltaY = 0;
            }
            else {
                if (lastYChange < 0 && yChange > 0) {
                    counter += 1;

                    textViewDirection.setText("Direction: Top");
                    textViewCounter.setText("Counter: " + counter);
                }
                else if (lastYChange > 0 && yChange < 0) {
                    counter += 1;

                    textViewDirection.setText("Direction: Bottom");
                    textViewCounter.setText("Counter: " + counter);
                } 

                lastYChange = yChange;
            }

            lastY = y;

            textViewAcceleration.setText("Acceleration is: " + deltaY);
        }
    }
```

So if I move phone in only one direction, for example top direction, `counter` should be increased by only 1, and `textViewDirection` should have value of `"Direction: Top"`.
Instead, with this code counter is increased multiple times and `textViewDirection` is switching from `"Direction: Top"` and `"Direction: Down"`.

Does anyone know to fix this? So that, for example, if I move phone up, then down, then up, `counter` should have value of 3, and `textViewDirection` should have value `"Direction: Top"`, `"Direction: Down"` and `"Direction: Top"`, respectively.

Comment: this answer your question I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884057/is-it-possible-to-measure-the-how-far-the-phone-travels-vertically

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ If you feel the question is answered by another question, then it's helpful to vote-to-close as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to measure the how far the phone travels vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884057/is-it-possible-to-measure-the-how-far-the-phone-travels-vertically)

Answer (score 0):

[This is a possible accelerometer result when you move the sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw6Vh.png) Unfortunately, y accelerometer waveform is not as straightforward to behave as you thought in your code. It oscillates a lot, e.g. when you stop the device